# The table "users" for activerecord class "User" cannot be found in the database

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have been installing yii users and rights and have followed [this link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/423/installing-yii-users-and-rights-to-newly-created-yii-app/).

When I type in the url `http://localhost/ur_project/user/login`, this asks for the username and password. but when I enter the username and password it gives me an error.

```
The table "users" for activerecord class "User" cannot be found in the database.
```

Comment: have you created the tables for user?

Comment: yes it exists in the database

Comment: please show the exact name of table for users, the code for user model, and your table prefix (if exist) you find this last in  db entry of config/main.php

Comment: yes thanks found it, users was written instead of user. 'tableUsers' => 'user',

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT id, username, email, createtime, lastvisit, superuser, status, password, activkey FROM `user` `t` WHERE `t`.`username`=:yp0 LIMIT 1                                                                                                                now i am getting this error, can you tell me what is wrong with this..??

Comment: This is because the code looking for a column not in db. show you table schema please

Comment: you talking about the user table objects..?

Comment: yes the table related to the error

Comment: user_id,username, password, email,gender,activekey, create_at,lastvisit_at,superuser, status,salt,requires_new_password,login_attempts,login_time,login_ip,activation_key, validation_key,create_time, update_time,reset_token,profilepic,address                                                these are the objects of user table

Comment: Please update (edit) the question  and format the code properly ... so is difficult to understand..

Comment: The table user is create by you or came form some migration / installation?

Comment: CDbCommand::fetch() failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown
column 'id' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT id,
username, email, createtime, lastvisit, superuser, status, password,
activkey FROM `user` `t` WHERE `t`.`username`=:yp0 LIMIT 1.
in
C:\wamp\www\emergency_response\protected\modules\user\components\UserIdentity.php
(27)
in
C:\wamp\www\emergency_response\protected\modules\user\models\UserLogin.php
(52)
in
C:\wamp\www\emergency_response\protected\modules\user\controllers\LoginController.php
(19)

Comment: this is the exact error as i copied it as it is by activating debugging and i have mentioned the user table objects, there is no other way i can make it ore understandable
sorry for this bro

Comment: this is created by me in mysql workbench

Comment: Please. first update your question and add the user table schema properly formatted. second eventually add in you questio e this last comment (errror code) third tell me if the table is created by you or  is based on some migration/installaion

Comment: Here are deep night i look at your response tomorrow

Comment: thanks, i looked into this, there was problem with my db..!!
done with this.
well i have another error regarding adding bootstrap to webapp/protected/modules/user/admin/view files.
"Property "BsGridView.ajaxType" is not defined. "

Comment: Is better for you publish another question. in this way all the community can see it not only you and i. If you think the suggestion of check the exact table name is was useful i can post the suggestione like an answer and you can rate it.

Comment: i have posted the question already. i also thought of posting it in this comment. though you would respond more quickly.. :)

Comment: Please Rate my answer below, I'm lookin for your new question

Comment: i have rated it but once i have a reputation of 15, my vote will be publically shown..!!

Comment: At the moment  i think you can also rate as useful  (upper arrow near answer)

Comment: i have done it, once i have earn a total of 15 reputation my votes will change the publicly  displayed post score..!!

Comment: hi, need to ask one question.
i have installed yii user and rights and upon login through "webapp/user/login" it takes me to the index page. but i want to direct admin to some other page rather then index.php..
can to tell me how to do it.

Comment: Hi @Salik Asad, is related to the render o redirect you have assigned in Action/login. But ask this like another question, this permit to  more people help you. comment here when you have posted the new question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the exact name of table for users, chek in db and in code for user model, check also for prefix  and your table prefix (if exist) you find this last in db entry of config/main.php